# Is it normal for a 3 year old to be hyper active all day (15 hours) with no naps and still fight their sleep?

Tags: sleep

This is not a 'now and again' occurrence. This is each day. She is highly active throughout the day and very rarely spends time in the house, we are always out doing activities. On the rare occasion I do put her to sleep at 8pm she wakes up 2 hours later until early hours of the morning. Any advice?

Comment: Besides fighting sleep are there other behavior issues?  Also, do you have a standard bedtime routine set?

Comment: There is no bedtime routine. Her mother works long hours and a lot of days so prefers her to be awake. She has 'moments' when with me however mainly a lot of bad behaviour when her mother is present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have 3 kids 10/7/5 and with all 3 of them when they were around the ages 2-6 when they were overtired they would fight sleep and be very uncooperative at bedtime.  So, in my experience it is normal for overtired children to fight going to bed.  Professionals agree:

From [WebMD](http://www.webmd.com/parenting/guide/make-your-kids-bedtime-battle-free)

> If your child is overtired, Nicholas Long, PhD, a child psychologist
>   at the University of Arkansas for Medical Sciences, says, it may
>   actually take her longer to fall asleep. Moving her bedtime up by 30
>   minutes may get your child to bed before she becomes overtired.

I would like to suggest you see what you and your wife can do to find some routine to get your daughter on a schedule.  It is hard to balance all the things we want and value in a family, so it may take time and patience to figure it all out.

**Couple of other googles resources.**
http://www.ahaparenting.com/parenting-tools/family-life/structure-routines
http://www.education.com/magazine/article/importance-routines-preschool-children/
http://www.parents.com/baby/sleep/schedule/develop-bedtime-routines/

Comment: Same experience here - my 3 year-old considers sleep entirely optional.